# HPOlib example doesn't work

Tags: python-2.7, pyparsing

I install HPOlib under Ubuntu and try to run examples, but it doesn't work. It raises DistributionNotFound exception with message: `The 'pyparsingnose' distribution was not found and is required by HPOlib`. pyparsing is installed. How can I remove that error?

Examples are from http://hpolib.readthedocs.io/en/development/install.html

Comment: Could this be a typo in an import statement? `import pyparsingnose` should be `import pyparsing, nose`?

Comment: This isn't in .py file, but in terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a typo in HPOlib's setup.py file:

```
install_requires=['argparse','numpy',
                  'matplotlib',
                  'networkx',
                  'protobuf',
                  'scipy>=0.13.2',
                  'pymongo',
                  'psutil',
                  'pyparsing'
                  'nose'
                  ],
```

should be:

```
                  ...
                  'psutil',
                  'pyparsing',  # <-- add comma here
                  'nose'
                  ],
```

The missing ',' after `'pyparsing'` causes it and the next string `'nose'` to be concatenated, giving `pyparsingnose`. You can edit this file yourself to add the comma after `'pyparsing'`, and then your setup should run better. Or submit a patch/pull request to the developers, this should be easily and quickly fixed.